# HTTParty adds params from :options hash multiple times to URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, uri, parameters, httparty

HTTParty.get is adding parameters multiple times to the URI it sends.  Has anyone else come across this before?

```
def initialize(address)
   self.address = address
   self.base_uri = 'https://api.randomapi.com/street-address'
end

def get
  response = HTTParty.get(base_uri, :query => {
    :street => address.street.strip,
  })
end
```

If this I format a request this way:

```
HTTParty.get(base_uri, :query => {:street=>"random street"})
```

This is the URI is sends.  Note how many times the `street` param is added.

```
#<URI::HTTPS:0x007fbc78582d70 URL:https://api.randomapi.com/street-address?street=random%20street&street=random%20street&street=random%20street&street=random%20street>
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a bug in the gem(https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/185 ,  https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/pull/189).  I upgraded to 0.11 and it fixed the duplicate parameters problem.